# How to add images in PHML file in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento

I am working in Magento 1.9. I want to add images in form in phtml file. For this I have made an array in Block directory.

```
public function one_rate_img() {
    return array (
        0  =>  $this->getSkinUrl('images/Envelope-172x115.png'),
        2  =>  $this->getSkinUrl('images/Envelope-172x115.png'),
        6  =>  $this->getSkinUrl('images/Envelope-172x115.png'),
        8  =>  $this->getSkinUrl('images/Envelope-172x115.png'),
        10 =>  $this->getSkinUrl('images/Envelope-172x115.png'),
        12 =>  $this->getSkinUrl('images/Envelope-172x115.png'),
    );
}
```

When I call that function in phtml, it displays the path of images but it should display images.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing PHP code with HTML. I leave you here a little example in PHP to display those images:

```
<?php
function one_rate_img(){
    return [
        0 => $this->getSkinUrl('images/Envelope-172x115.png'), 
        2 => $this->getSkinUrl('images/Envelope-172x115.png'), 
        6 => $this->getSkinUrl('images/Envelope-172x115.png'), 
        8 => $this->getSkinUrl('images/Envelope-172x115.png'), 
        10 => $this->getSkinUrl('images/Envelope-172x115.png'), 
        12 => $this->getSkinUrl('images/Envelope-172x115.png'),  
    ]; 
} 

$imagesToDisplay = one_rate_img();
foreach ($imagesToDisplay as $key => $image):
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';
endforeach;
?>
```

Kind regards